OpenAIEmbeddings works fine but AzureOpenAIEmbeddings gives error: 'str' object has no attribute 'create'
I am implementing simple RAG using AzureOpenAI. It was working fine till I was directly using the OpenAIEmbeddings but when I deployed "text-embedding-ada-002" model on Azure and tried using the embeddings with that, it shows the error: 'str' object has no attribute 'create'
import openai
from langchain_community.document_loaders import PyMuPDFLoader
from langchain_openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain_community.vectorstores.faiss import FAISS
from langchain_openai import AzureOpenAIEmbeddings

loader = PyMuPDFLoader("test.pdf")
pages = loader.load_and_split()

#below works fine if I use it in place of Azure embeddings
embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings(openai_api_key=api_key)

#below gives error
embeddings_AZ = AzureOpenAIEmbeddings(openai_api_key=OPENAI_API_KEY, deployment=OPENAI_EMBEDDING_MODEL_NAME, client="azure", chunk_size=1)

#here it gives error 'str' object has no attribute 'create'
pdfDocSearch = FAISS.from_documents(pages, embedding = embeddings_AZ)

I tried it with changing or passing multiple parameters like:
AzureOpenAIEmbeddings(openai_api_key=OPENAI_API_KEY, document_model_name=OPENAI_EMBEDDING_MODEL_NAME, chunk_size=1, deployment=OPENAI_EMBEDDING_MODEL_NAME, client="azure")

Also I replaced AzureOpenAIEmbeddings with OpenAIEmbeddings as:
OpenAIEmbeddings(openai_api_key=OPENAI_API_KEY, document_model_name=OPENAI_EMBEDDING_MODEL_NAME, chunk_size=1, deployment=OPENAI_EMBEDDING_MODEL_NAME, client="azure")

but nothing is working. It should not give error and Azure embeddings should also work as direct OpenAIEmbeddings are working.

provide the endpoint when using AzureOpenAIEmbeddings

check this doc https://python.langchain.com/v0.2/docs/integrations/text_embedding/azureopenai/

I could able to figure out that I need to provide the proxy as it is running behind a firewall:
  embeddings = AzureOpenAIEmbeddings(
        azure_deployment=os.getenv("AZURE_OPENAI_EMBEDDING_MODEL_NAME"),
        openai_api_version=os.getenv("AZURE_OPENAI_API_VERSION"),
        azure_endpoint = os.getenv("AZURE_OPENAI_ENDPOINT"), 
        api_key=os.getenv("AZURE_OPENAI_API_KEY"),  
        http_client=httpx.Client(proxy=os.getenv("AZURE_OPENAI_HTTP_PROXY")) 
 )

#providing proxy fixed the issue.
